# How to import an icebox encrypted wallet into Geth

Tags: go-ethereum, private-key, import

I am trying to take the encrypted keyfile from icebox and import into Geth.  However I am coming up with this error when I try

```
geth account import icebox.txt
```

Fatal: Failed to load the private key: encoding/hex: invalid byte: U+007B '{'

The keystore file is a v2 keystore file.  I would import via something like myetherwallet but there is no v2 compatibility.  I was told that geth still had compatibility to import v2 keystore files and automatically import them into v3.

The reason I am trying to do this is to get my private key for this account.  So, if anyone knows another way to get a private key from a v2 keystore file (like found in icebox) that solution would work too.

Answer (score 1):

Oh hey. You know what I just realized. You have it in your keystore folder and can see it in the accounts list in geth right? What if you then do:

`> eth account update [<uuid>|<address> , ... ]  // Decrypt and re-encrypt given keys.`

[Source](http://ethdocs.org/en/latest/account-management.html)

That will prompt for a new password I believe and therefore re-encrypt and hopefully re-encrypt with v3 of the JSON?

You know what would be even easier? If MyEtherWallet just supported v2 of JSONs! I've added it to the to-do list but, life is crazy right now. Maybe we can push with HF stuff.

Comment: No, unfortunately I can't see the file in the accounts list in geth.  I think I just can't use icebox until they have v3 capability because I have no way to find my private key from their encrypted keystore.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [pyicebox](https://github.com/badmofo/pyicebox) to extract a geth compatible keyfile from a given mnemonic.

Follow these steps:

1. download https://github.com/badmofo/pyicebox/blob/master/icebox.py
2. install dependencies: `pip install mnemonic scrypt bitcoin ethereum`
3. extract private keys: `python icebox.py keys`, enter your mnemonic
4. export keyfile: `python icebox.py export`, enter the corresponding key