# What is the correct encoding for geth keystore files?

Tags: go-ethereum, keystore, encoding

I'm attempting to import a transcribed geth `UTC--...` format keyfile into geth on ubuntu, using [this guidance](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/465/how-to-import-a-plain-private-key-into-geth-or-mist?rq=1), and am getting the following error:

`Fatal: Failed to load the private key: encoding/hex: invalid byte: U+007 B '{'`

There are a few other similar questions but none ask why this error occurs.

- [Importing paper wallet using geth gives encoding error](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/1991/importing-paper-wallet-using-geth-gives-encoding-error)
- [Import private key into ethereum wallet](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/3873/import-private-key-into-ethereum-wallet)
- [How to import an icebox encrypted wallet into Geth](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/7156/how-to-import-an-icebox-encrypted-wallet-into-geth)
- [Export Parity private key](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/19577/export-parity-private-key)

I'm guessing the file must be in `UTF-8` encoding. On using `file -i` on a terminal it returns:

`UTC--etc_file_name text/plain; charset=us-ascii`

I think `us-ascii` is a subset of `UTF-8`, so it should work....

**Why is this error occuring?**

**What is the correct encoding for geth keystore files?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not know why this error is occuring, but:

- I'm on ubuntu, and  `file -i keyfile`  
  gives the same result as for you.
  As I have no problem with my key,
  it is probably not an encoding problem in your side.
- The '{' character is used to format the keyfile. 
  My file format is:
  `{"address":x,"crypto":{"cipher":"aes-128-ctr","ciphertext":x,"cipherparams":{"iv":x},"kdf":"scrypt","kdfparams":{"dklen":x,"n":x,"p":x,"r":x,"salt":x},"mac":x},"id":x,"version":x}`

  so it should be something like that in your file.
- You should verify that your '{' and your quotes (") are all balanced, 
  because it seems to me that it comes from such a mistake.
  However, if you did not modify the file, it should not have occured.
  Note that some fields have quotes in their value (e.g. hex fields)
  while others have not.

Answer (score 0):

This stemmed from a mistake:

I needed to save the file to `/.ethereum/keystore`

I had it saved in `/.ethereum`

I was also not completely clear on how geth interprets private-key, encryted private key and keystore info:

**encryted private-key:** stored in "ciphertext" field of JSON keystore file, encryted with settings in that file.

**private key** un-encryted version of above (this is what most of the linked questions refer to) - I was attempting to import the whole JSON file, not just the key! Hence the error with invalid `{` char.

**JSON keystore file** this is what I was attempting to import, but saved to incorrect directory then jumped to "oh maybe there's an import procedure..." search and went up a blind alley..